# How to write a form using Bootstrap 4 without affecting the background of the body?

Tags: css, forms, bootstrap-4, background

I am using Bootstrap 4 in order to style my website but the problem is that I already have a CSS file that includes the background color and image in the background, and after I link the bootstrap 4 it ruins the style and the background becomes white like the original background is hidden.

How can I create a form without affecting the background of it?

In the image below, the original background color was skyblue but once I include the Bootstrap link it partially overrides the color.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

maybe you can show some of your code. here an example of the bootstrap form that i put inside a container. and the Codepen link is available below if you want take a look:

```
<div class="container box">
<form>
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="inputEmail4">Email</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail4" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="inputPassword4">Password</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword4" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="inputCity">City</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputCity">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
      <label for="inputState">State</label>
      <select id="inputState" class="form-control">
        <option selected>Choose...</option>
        <option>...</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
      <label for="inputZip">Zip</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputZip">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="form-check">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="gridCheck">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridCheck">
        Check me out
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign in</button>
</form>

</div>
```

[Here an example Bootstrap form on sky blue background](https://codepen.io/ozy-cozy/pen/vqMvOm)

Comment: this is not what i am asking for . thank you for your time